# is it possible to create object pool similar to string?

Tags: java

as jvm manages string pool for String from which it looks up for any new String assignment, similarly, can we develop a pool of any other object or primitives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interning pool for Java String constants is something known to the Java compiler, so you cannot mimic the exact behavior by yourself.

The pool itself, however, is nothing more than a hash map. If your object has a suitable identifier, you can certainly roll a pool for your own objects: simply create a static method that takes a key, looks it up in a static hash map, and builds a new object only if it has not been pooled yet. Note, however, that in orde for this simple scheme to work, it is essential for your object to be immutable.

Comment: so basically maintaining a static hashMap would replicate the pooling. right?
and that means lesser the number of fields in pooled-type, more effective/efficient the caching would be?

Comment: @ay89 In general, the pooling is going to be efficient only when there is a lot of duplication among the objects that you create. You can have an object with 30 fields representing a customer, along with his address, phone numbers, etc. If you have only 100 customers, your pooling will be very efficient even with classes that have lots of fields. If, on the other hand, you try pooling classes that represent coordinates in 2D (pairs of integers), and use it on a set of 10,000 randomly generated coordinates, the caching is not going to be efficient at all, even though there are only two fields.

Comment: ok, but if there are more duplicate objects of larger number of fields, pooling will be efficient in terms of memory. but at the same time, i think, it will consume more time, comparing larger number of fields to decide whether object is duplicate or not. right?

Answer (score 3):

String pool is not the only pool / cache in Java, Integer and other wrapper classes use  cache, you can take a look at the Integer source code as an example

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

you can also take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool//